# How to open /opt folder in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I installed ubuntu 13.04

In the GUI File Manager i dont file "file system" which take me to /

How to access /opt in file manager

Answer (score 5):

If you can't see by using Nautilus, you can try using the Terminal.

[image: Terminal screenshot of the commands]

Open the Terminal and type **cd /**
Now you are in the / folder. If you want, type **ls** to list all the folders and files in that folder.
Now, you can type **cd opt** to enter the opt folder. Again, type ls to see the folders and files in there.

Maybe it won't help you at all, but is all I can think about...
Unless, of course, if you tried to install a different file manager.

You can try this ones: Nemo, Thunar and Dolphin, which are the ones I know, but only by name, I've never used.
Just search for them in the Ubuntu Software Center!

Answer (score 3):

From your terminal you can just run the command `nautilus /opt`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. type `cd /` and click enter (this will navigate you to the root folder).
2. type `cd opt` and click enter (this will change the current directory to the opt directory).
3. type `nautilus .` and click enter

NOTE: When we type `nautilus .` in the terminal it will open the current folder in the file manager.

Comment: For a beginner in this way he knows how the processing is done.